# Empty post request Laravel/Nginx

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

I'm expecting a strange error lately.

I'm tracking every error (even soft) from my website and something strange is happening.

1% of user that compile a form sent via post send empty data. Nothing in the post not even the hidden values or the name of the fields. There is also a js validation in this form that could prevent an empty submit.

I'm using Laravel + Nginx. I've track all data but the problem seems not coming from Laravel (I'm tracking POST submission data as first thing in the index.php of laravel and it looks already empty). I've added post data in nginx logs and it looks empty when the error occurs.

It affects mostly mobile devices (of all kind) but also desktop (of all kind).

I've tracked all different form and error come from all forms indistinctly that made a post to this url.

Any idea?

Comment: Are there any posibilities that it's a bot? What is the url referer of the `POST` request?

Comment: Ref empty, maybe you are right

Comment: Doing a reverse ip it like some requests empty are coming from xdsl, so unless someone is playing at home with a webserver it looks strange to me...